# How to use include or join into with a each method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a little advice about the `join` and `includes` methods.

I display a list of groups in the index view. Each has a modal associated, and, in this modal, I would like to display the requests associated to this group. Normally, I'd use `@requests = group.requests`, but would like to use `join` for sending just one request to my database.

Since I'm in the index view, I don't have a `@`group in my action.

controller:

```
def index
  @groups = current_user.groups
end
```

view (index):

```
<% @groups.each do |g| %>
  <MODAL>
    <% @requests = g.requests %>
    <% @requests.each do |r| %>
      <%= r.date %>
    <% end %>
  </MODAL>
<% end %>
```

I guess I can also use `join` and `include` for `@groups`, but there is already one SQL request, so I'm good with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We need you to put in effort to format your document correctly, and use correct grammar and spelling. SO isn't a discussion list, it's an online reference book, and as such, grammar, spelling and readability are important.

Comment: Ok, @theTinMan, I'm gonna make an effort for that. But I'm not a native english, so I do my best about the grammar ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, add includes like this to preload requests and avoid n+1 queries.

```
def index
  @groups = current_user.groups.includes(:requests)
end
```

View is fine, but you can also write as:-

```
<% @groups.each do |g| %>
  <MODAL>
    <% g.requests.each do |r| %>
      <%= r.date %>
    <% end %>
  </MODAL>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @rohan, and how should i call the <%=@requests%> after that ?

Comment: I've tried something like that : group(:requests).each but is not working :(

Comment: your code in the view is fine. you have to loop through groups. But since you have already eager-loaded associated requests in memory, it will not make sql query to get them. Maybe, you can save a line of code by writing g.requests.each do |r| in the view. But it is same thing

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what i'm looking for, your making my day much better like this @rohan.